# Error encountered while configuring the stage: 'null' while running custom code in python transform, data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I was trying to write a custom python code in the python transform plugin in data fusion. I tried to run the example code in the documentation and even created sample data to match the documentation. The plugin seems to throw this error- Error encountered while configuring the stage: 'null'. Is this a bug in the plugin?

Comment: Can you please provide complete stack trace and also pipeline json? Please make sure to redact any sensitive information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and solved

all you have to do is: select the function description and then click on `shift + Tab` to make a back a little bit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxGQ1.png)

OR you can just remove the function description, and it will work fine.

also, make sure that the last line `emitter.emit(record)` back a little bit, to be in the right space of function body